# Excel Macro - Test if Power Query for Excel Addin in installed

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to test if "Power Query for Excel" add-in is installed and enable using excel macros ?
I'd like to use it to authorize the Data refreshing of my workbook which is connected to several data sources using this add-in.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this, as it's a COM add-in:

```
Function IsPowerQueryAvailable() As Boolean
    Dim bAvailable As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    bAvailable = Application.COMAddIns("Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel").Connect
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsPowerQueryAvailable = bAvailable
End Function
```

If you actually wanted to try and enable it as well if it is present, you could use something like this:

```
Function IsPowerQueryConnected() As Boolean
    Dim bAvailable      As Boolean
    Dim oPQ             As COMAddIn
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPQ = Application.COMAddIns("Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel")
    If Not oPQ Is Nothing Then
        If Not oPQ.Connect Then oPQ.Connect = True
        bAvailable = oPQ.Connect
    End If
    IsPowerQueryConnected = bAvailable
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if addin is installed by:

```
AddIns("AddInName").Installed
```

ie:

```
Sub Foo()
If AddIns("AddIn name").Installed Then
  'installed
Else
  'not installed
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The problem is that "Microsoft Power Query  for Excel" is a COM Add-in and is not in the same location that the other Add-ins.  I finally test the file location exists: <b>Dim DirFile As String
DirFile = "C:\Windows\System32\ccmcore.dll"

If Len(Dir(DirFile)) <> 0 Then ... end if</b>