# Excel-VBA show Warning if Addon is not Installed

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I am using an Excel 2013 file, which was updated by me to use PowerQuery for easier Data imports.

It already uses VBA Macros and i would like to include a Warning/MsgBox with a link to download PowerQuery, if it is not already installed.

How would i check for the existence of PowerQuery on the host System?

Comment: You may need additional version check as 2016 and  above will include PowerQuery by default

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201107/excel-macro-test-if-power-query-for-excel-addin-in-installed    and then you would simply add a msgbox with download link

Comment: @QHarr the solution from the provided link works great. But is the version check for 2016 still necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting the code by Rory at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201107/excel-macro-test-if-power-query-for-excel-addin-in-installed) i provided you would have something like the following. Note: You could use Rory's additional code to handle 2016 version or earlier ensuring if present is installed.

As you can't use a hyperlink direct i have adapted the Wiktor Stribiżew's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705916/putting-a-hyperlink-in-a-messagebox) that allows the user to click OK to go to the download site after getting msgbox  saying not installed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub IsPowerQueryAvailable()
    Dim downloadlink As String
    downloadlink = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379"

    Dim bAvailable As Boolean

    If Application.Version >= 16 Then
        bAvailable = True
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        bAvailable = Application.COMAddIns("Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel").Connect
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not bAvailable Then DownloadPowerQuery downloadlink
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DownloadPowerQuery(downloadlink As String)

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim Message As String
    Dim Wscript As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Message = MsgBox("Would you like to download PowerQuery?", vbYesNo, "Powerquery not available")

    If Message = vbYes Then
        objShell.Run (downloadlink)
    Else
        Wscript.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the Download should only be executed if bAvailable is false. Else it is a perfect working example. Thanks

Comment: @d3rdon Edit made so hopefully does as expected